# PermissionError: [Errno 13] при попытке записать QR-код во временный файл

Tags: python, html, flask, url, qrcode

```
@app.route('/gen')
def generate():
    random_url = str(uuid.uuid4())
    fake_qr = pyqrcode.create(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/{random_url}')
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.svg', delete=True) as temp_file:
        file_path = temp_file.name
        fake_qr.svg(file_path, scale=8)
        return render_template('gen.html', qr=file_path)
```

Я хочу чтобы сайт генерировал QR который ведет по указанному url, отправлял картинку в виде qr, а затем удалял ее, чтобы уже в html принять это как параметр src, но почему-то вылезает ошибка доступ запрещен. С чем это может быть связано если PyCharm запущен от имени администратора а доступ к папкам открыт?

Comment: Что-то похожее здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23212435/14585419. Попробуйте установить `NamedTemporaryFile` параметры `mode='w'` и `delete=False`, и удаллить файл уже после

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` создает файл и открывает его на запись. Вы путь к этому файлу передаете в `fake_qr.svg(file_path, scale=8)`, метод `fake_qr.svg()` пытается этот файл еще раз открыть (чтобы записать в него svg), и падает с ошибкой, потому что файл уже открыт.

Вам в принципе не нужно создавать файл, нужно просто получить имя и путь для временного файла, файл создаст метод `fake_qr.svg()`.

Как вариант - создаете временную директорию, в ней можно будет создавать файлы с любыми именами:

```
import tempfile
from pathlib import Path

...

@app.route('/gen')
def generate():
    random_url = str(uuid.uuid4())
    fake_qr = pyqrcode.create(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/{random_url}')
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(delete=True) as temp_directory:
        file_path = str(Path(temp_directory) / "file.svg")
        fake_qr.svg(file_path, scale=8)
        return render_template('gen.html', qr=file_path)
```

Директория вместе с временным файлом будет удалена при выходе из блока `with`

---

P.S., а вообще, `pyqrcode` умеет писать в предоставленный файловый объект, см. [документацию метода svg](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/moddoc.html#pyqrcode.QRCode.svg):

> The file parameter is used to
> specify where to write the document to. It can either be a writable (binary)
> stream or a file path.

Так что можно просто передать `temp_file` вместо пути:

```
@app.route('/gen')
def generate():
    random_url = str(uuid.uuid4())
    fake_qr = pyqrcode.create(f'http://127.0.0.1:5000/{random_url}')
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.svg', delete=True) as temp_file:
        fake_qr.svg(temp_file, scale=8)
        file_path = temp_file.name
        return render_template('gen.html', qr=file_path)
```

---

По поводу подстановки в `<img src=...>` - так работать не будет, вы путь передаете, причем путь ко временном файлу, удаленному после `return`, а нужен вообще url, а не путь в файловой системе.

Проще содержимое svg файла в html шаблон подставить, без строки `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` (для этого в метод svg нужно передавать параметр `xmldecl=False`) и без экранирования тегов.